# Writing SQL query with WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql

how can i write this task in sql ?

**-- where the country has more than 10 titles**

Answer (score 1):

```
create table cities (country varchar(100),city(100))
insert into cities (country ,city)
values('Country1','C1')
values('Country2','C21')
values('Country3','C13')
values('Country4','C14')
values('Country5','C15')
values('Country6','C16')
values('Country7','C17')
values('Country8','C18')
values('Country1','C2')
values('Country1','C3')
values('Country1','C4')
```

To filter aggregate value you need to use `having` clause

```
select country from cities group by country
having count(city)>10
```

Comment: Missing `GROUP BY country`

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, I missed it